# Displaying details of a post in a sidebar

Tags: theme-development, widgets, sidebar

I am developing a wordpress theme but m still new into and was learning. Basically, its a theme for resource website which provides web templates. In my theme i've created a **details section** in sidebar in which their are few few options like "***file size***" , "***file-type***", "***no of files***" in which in every post user have to provide these entries and it will be displayed in sidebar. So, anybody here plzz help and suggest something..??

Screenshot of details section in posts page is given below :

[image]

Comment: Please file an [edit] and add all your relevant research/code and explain where you are lacking

Comment: sir m very much confused and m not getting what to do...

Comment: codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields this would help you.

Comment: bro m using "custom post type with custom meta boxes" but it's showing information in content area of a post but i want to display information in sidebar so what shud i have to do??

Comment: In the link I gave to you is information how to get custom fields / meta boxes from post and how to display them in your desired area.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom fields to your posts and get it in sidebar.
For add easy custom fields: [Rilwis's meta box](https://github.com/rilwis/meta-box) and for get its:

```
$getted = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_meta_name', true);
```

Comment: Sir, I know how to add custom fields with the help of plugins but I want to add custom fields in my theme without plugins... How can I do that?? I want when i write something in custom field then it shoud display in sidebar rather then displaying in a post...

Comment: Check ds link http://newskoolstudios.net/exotic.php

Comment: You can add custom field with original wp. https://yadi.sk/i/f2F_3DT1cnSCD And you can use same you want with in my answer